# Is it possible to search an entry for specific table content

Tags: search, table-field

Considering the way table field content is saved to the database, could I search entries for content in a specific column?

So, say I have a table field containing X column, I would only want to search for an ID, located in column 3. Did anyone ever successfully try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible using the native search functionality.

You can search for a specific value within a table field using:

```
{% set results = craft.entries.search('tableField:"ID"') %}
```

That should return all entries that contain "ID" in `tableField`, but it doesn't restrict the search to a particular column in the table.

How likely is it that the ID will occur in other columns of the table?

Comment: In case of the ID, not likely. But, the column I search for could be partially the same as another column. I'll just have to make sure it isn't, then ;)